# R paste polygon coordinates for SQL

Tags: r, polygon, sql, polygon-creation

Everyone,

I am new to this GIS data and SQL, but have pretty decent R knowledge.

I am looking to extract the Polygon coordinates from a list so that I can paste into a SQL input query.

I am pulling data from here: https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2021/kml/cb_2021_08_tract_500k.zip

From here I am converting the .kml file (in the .zip file) to a .geojson in Visual Studio Code using the Geo Data Viewer extension

here is what I have code wise

```
# Load the package required to read JSON files.
library(geojsonsf)
library(sf)

#set working directory and file path
setwd("C:\\Users\\XXXX\\OneDrive - XXXX\\Documents\\R Scripts")
files <- list.files(getwd(),pattern = ".geojson")

# Convert GEOJSON file to a data frame.
result <- geojsonsf::geojson_sf(paste0("./", files))

#remove columns not needed
results <- result[c("GEOID", "geometry")]

#Convert geometry to Polygon coordinates. Testing on the the 1st row only

> sf::st_cast(result$geometry[[1]], "POLYGON")
POLYGON Z ((-104.875223 39.743785 0, -104.875227 39.740212 0, -104.865803 39.7402 0, -104.865804 39.743787 0, -104.87403 39.74379 0, -104.875223 39.743785 0))
```

You can see I am getting the coordinates I need:
POLYGON Z ((-104.875223 39.743785 0, -104.875227 39.740212 0, -104.865803 39.7402 0, -104.865804 39.743787 0, -104.87403 39.74379 0, -104.875223 39.743785 0))

I want to be bale to paste those coordinates in the a SQL input script.

```
paste0("INSERT INTO [ExternalData].[dbo].[GeoCensusBlock2] (BlockCode,[Polygon]) VALUES ('",
       Properties["GEOID"], "',geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((",

        , # paste here the coordinates 

        "))', 4326))")
```

looking for an output like this:

```
INSERT INTO [ExternalData].[dbo].[GeoCensusBlock2] (BlockCode,[Polygon]) VALUES ('080579556001',geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-104.875223 39.743785 0, -104.875227 39.740212 0, -104.865803 39.7402 0, -104.865804 39.743787 0, -104.87403 39.74379 0, -104.875223 39.743785 0))', 4326))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `st_read()` to read kml files directly wthout the need to transform them to geojson externally.

```r
library(sf)

sf <- st_read("cb_2021_08_tract_500k.kml")
#> Reading layer `cb_2021_08_tract_500k' from data source 
#>   `cb_2021_08_tract_500k.kml' using driver `KML'
#> Simple feature collection with 1447 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XYZ
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -109.0603 ymin: 36.99243 xmax: -102.0415 ymax: 41.00344
#> z_range:       zmin: 0 zmax: 0
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
```

Regarding the desired string containing coordinates, would this work?

```
# extract coordinates
c <- sf[1, ] |> st_cast("POLYGON") |> st_coordinates()
head(c)
#>              X        Y Z L1 L2
#> [1,] -104.8847 39.74381 0  1  1
#> [2,] -104.8846 39.74016 0  1  1
#> [3,] -104.8752 39.74021 0  1  1
#> [4,] -104.8658 39.74020 0  1  1
#> [5,] -104.8658 39.74379 0  1  1
#> [6,] -104.8740 39.74379 0  1  1 

# concat string from matrix considering x, y, z
s <- apply(c[, 1:3], 1, paste, collapse = " ") |> paste(collapse = ", ")
s
#> [1] "-104.884652 39.743807 0, -104.884646 39.740156 0, -104.875227 39.740212 0, -104.865803 39.7402 0, -104.865804 39.743787 0, -104.87403 39.74379 0, -104.875223 39.743785 0, -104.884652 39.743807 0"
```

Comment: Thanks, that is the one function I did not look at after a few hours of this. Thanks for you help.