# R SQL importing Polygon errors System.FormatException: 24119

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sql, geometry, kml

Any advice here from you all.

I am converting a .kml file in R and uploading the data to SQL.

I am pulling data from here: https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2021/kml/cb_2021_08_tract_500k.zip

Using hte R sf package

```
setwd(getwd())
files <- list.files(getwd(),pattern = ".kml")
sf <- st_read("cb_2021_08_tract_500k.kml")
```

Then I am extracting and creating a SQL insert command

```
result <- sf[464, ] |> st_cast("POLYGON") |> st_coordinates()
  
  #result[,4:5] <- ifelse(result[,4:5] >1, 1, result[,4:5])
  
  #get Names of Properties 
  Properties <- as.numeric(sub(".*\\D(\\d+).*", "\\1", sf$Name[i]))

  #Get Geo-Coordinates
  Geometry <- apply(result[, 1:3], 1, paste, collapse = " ") |> paste(collapse = ", ")
  
  #make data frame of SQL input commands    
SQLquery <- paste0("INSERT INTO [xxxxx].[dbo].[xxxxxx] (BlockCode,[Polygon]) VALUES ('",
                                   Properties, "',geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((",
                                   Geometry,
                                   "))', 4326))")
 
 #Write SQL insert Statment
 odbc::dbGetQuery(conn, SQLquery)
```

This works from me in for loop for most of the coordinates, but I have a few errors I am getting from SQL.

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 01000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry": 
System.FormatException: 24119: The Polygon input is not valid because the start and end points of the exterior ring are not the same. Each ring of a polygon must have the same start and end points.
System.FormatException: 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GeometryValidator.ValidatePolygonRing(Int32 iRing, Int32 cPoints, Double firstX, Double firstY, Double lastX, Double lastY)
```

Example or SQL insert statement and coordinates for this error

```
INSERT INTO [xxxx].[dbo].[xxxx] (BlockCode,[Polygon]) VALUES ('81259632005',geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-104.904049 39.625436 0, -104.904032 39.624116 0, -104.902796 39.624304 0, -104.903285 39.625954 0, -104.903917 39.626829 0, -104.904049 39.625436 0, -104.904031 39.624088 0, -104.904105 39.60956 0, -104.897209 39.609563 0, -104.894826 39.609235 0, -104.893369 39.609282 0, -104.901864 39.624094 0, -104.904031 39.624088 0))', 4326))
```

Here is what I did to check my polygons giving me errors.
Refer to my question here: [R paste polygon coordinates for SQL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/438079/r-paste-polygon-coordinates-for-sql)

When I look at my polygon I am getting

```
GEOresults$geometry[464]
>Geometry set for 1 feature 
>Geometry type: GEOMETRYCOLLECTION
>Dimension:     XY
>Bounding box:  xmin: -104.904105 ymin: 39.609235 xmax: -104.893369 >ymax: 39.626829
>Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
>GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POLYGON Z ((-104.904049 39....
```

Looking my my polygon it is like this:

```
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POLYGON Z ((-104.904049 39.625436 0, -104.904032 39.624116 0, -104.902796 39.624304 0, -104.903285 39.625954 0, -104.903917 39.626829 0, -104.904049 39.625436 0)), POLYGON Z ((-104.904031 39.624088 0, -104.904105 39.60956 0, -104.897209 39.609563 0, -104.894826 39.609235 0, -104.893369 39.609282 0, -104.901864 39.624094 0, -104.904031 39.624088 0)))
```

Does the sf package have the ability to combine or convert the GEOMETRYCOLLECTION to a single polygon?

Comment: Can you narrow down which feature is causing the problem? There's 1447 of them and without an SQL Server setup like yours its hard to duplicate your error to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Edited question, but looks like my polygon is a GEOMETRYCOLLECTION

Comment: Here is what I have tried: ```st_cast(GEOresults$geometry[[464]], "MULTIPOLYGON")``` and ```st_cast(GEOresults$geometry[[464]], "POLYGON")``` for both only first part of geometrycollection is retained

Comment: Where's `GEOresults` come from? Its not created in your question (`sf` is the first thing you read from the data file), and element 464 for me is a simple MULTIPOLYGON. I'm using the same file/download as you give.

Comment: Also, you can probably use `st_as_text` to convert the geometry in the spatial data frame `sf` to the text for pasting into the SQL without having to demolish it into coordinates and then paste those back together. See what `st_as_text(st_cast(st_zm(sf$geometry[1]),"POLYGON"))` does. You might not even need the cast if your DB can accept any WKT geometry text.

Comment: Also, when checking geometry of your sf object using `sf::st_is_valid(sf)`, all objects seem to be fine when read from file.

Comment: @Spacedman I got the GEOreults from: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/438079/r-paste-polygon-coordinates-for-sql

Comment: @Spacedman I was able to use ```st_as_text(st_cast(st_zm(sf$geometry[1]),"POLYGON"))``` to separate out the polygons. I will use this to gather what I need. thanks for your help

Comment: An object called `GEOresults` isn't mentioned in that question, and is mentioned in this question without any clue where it came from. So we have to **guess** where it came from and if we get that wrong we might not be able to understand your question. A good question should give clear code that we can run to reproduce your problem.  You do well here (supplying link to data too!) until `GEOresults` appears from nowhere.